# Use Laravel features outside of it

Tags: laravel

Assume I have test.php file inside public folder. I want to read a table and dump it.

```
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;


$links = DB::select('select * from tbl_links ' );
dd($links);
```

Now I go to mydomain.ir/load.php .

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been
>   set. in
>   /home/dastanez/zanganli.ir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:258
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/dastanez/zanganli.ir/public/load.php(8):
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('select', Array) #1
>   {main} thrown in
>   /home/dastanez/zanganli.ir/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 258

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact error a while back - twice in two different projects.  One in Lumen, one in regular Laravel.

I solved it by uncommenting `$app->withFacades();` in **bootstrap/app.php** on Laravel 5.4.  For later versions, naming the facade helped on one of my errors:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
```

**More explanation if using Lumen:**

Lumen doesn't come with Facades activated. If you plan in using them, you must enable them under the `Create The Application` section, uncommenting this line:

```php
// $app->withFacades();
```

From there, you should be able to use the `create_alias()` function to add additional Facades into your application.